# javascript equivalent of php $$ dollar dollar

Tags: php, javascript, variable-variables

1. I have declared a local variable named cont in a function named validate.
2. I am calling a function process from inside validate.
3. I am sending the string 'cont' as argument to validate function.
4. In the process function using the string 'cont' i want to access the javascript local variable's value like window['cont']. But i get undefined.
5. What i am trying to do is trying to access variables like $GLOBALS in php or $$.

Here is an example of what i did.

```
<script>

function process(str)
{
   alert(window[str]);
}

function validate()
{
   var cont='once there lived a king named midas';
   process('cont')
}

validate();

</script>
```

The reason is i do most of the forms as ajax. i dont want to make a request string like this.

```
var param = "command=insert&content=" + encodeURIComponent(cont);
```

i want to do like this.

```
var param = makeParam('command,[insert],content,(cont)');
```

what i do in makeparam is i use regular expression to extract key value pairs.
so i get the string cont from (cont) and i substitute it into window variable like window[cont]. cont will have the string 'cont'.

so how do we get the content of a variable by using the name of the variable as string?

so i am looking for javascript equivalent of php's $$

**Edited**

a part of the code where i extract cont which is inside (cont) which means i want the content of the string between ().

```
nxt = str[i+1].match(/\((.*)\)$/)

if(nxt)param += '=' + encodeURIComponent(window[nxt[1]]);
```

the content of param would be

```
"command=insert&content=once there lived a king"
// assume that once there lived a king is encoded
```

---

**Edit. Note2.**

After few more responses i am editing the code to add this.

I am trying to do like $GLOBALS in php.

I haven't tried whether $GLOBALS would cantain local variables too.

and learned that local scope will not come into $GLOBALS.

---

**Update after reading Felix King's Update.**

I want to use a function which will construct a query string as simpler as possible. like the following.

```
var param = makeParam('command,insert,/title/,/keywords/,/description/,mode,[1],fckcontent,(cont)');

// if it is a text without // or () then the it is a straight key value pair. so i will do comment=insert.

//if it is /title/ then the key is title and its value is an input elements value with id as title so title=getElementById('title')

//if it is mode,[1] then mode is the key and 1 is its direct value//

//if it is fckcontent,(cont) then fckcontent is the key and cont is a javascript local variable which will contain html content from a WYSIWYG editor.

// a sample result will be

 var param = "command=insert&keywords=somekeywords&description=somedescription&mode=1&fckcontent=<p>once there lived a king<p>
```

and then casablanca stated that $GlOBALS will not contain local scope variables and that is the same way in javascript. that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validate()
{
   var cont='once there lived a king named midas';
   process('cont')
}
```

`cont` is defined in the **local scope** of the function, not in global scope. Either do just

```
cont='once there lived a king named midas';
```

(without `var`) or

```
window.cont='once there lived a king named midas';
```

**Update:**

But why do you want to go through so much trouble with parsing strings? Why don't you do:

```
var param = makeParam({command: 'insert', content: encodeURIComponent(cont)});
```

Comment: Yeah instead of using it as a global variable we can use like yours. nice. still, is there any other alternate? even if am thinking about something like $GLOBALS then yours is the way. besides, just thinking aloud for other alternatives. thank you.

Comment: i am answering this after your update. i want to do it like this. please refer my question under the bold section "UPDATE after reading Felix King's update".

Comment: aah. after all these discussions i have concluded. i am going to use your way. window.variable. thank you. for some time let us see other peoples answers so that i could make this post more stronger.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/archive/2007/06/14/variable_variables_in_javascri - found that, which might help you, or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592630/javascript-variable-variables

Comment: Both of the links above appear to be dead.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, but what you're expecting is wrong. `$GLOBALS` in PHP **does not** include local variables, and the same thing applies to `window` in JavaScript. `cont` is local to `validate`, so obviously it can't be accessed from `process`.

In PHP, you need to explicitly declare a variable as global inside a function. In JavaScript, it works the other way round: any variables declared using `var` are local, anything that is **not** declared is global.

Comment: ah, yes i was assuming that too. nice point. won't we get errors for undeclared local scope variables. what i am thinking to do is just assigning value to an undeclared local variable. i hope it should work. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that will work, and you won't get any error. Any variable that you don't declare is assumed to be global.

Comment: ok. thank you. now every thing is clear. yet, having hard feeling for using additional global variables for these purpose.

Comment: You could use a single global object for storing parameters, instead of several variables. Just define an empty object at the beginning, say `globals = {};`, and then you can use `globals['cont']` instead of `cont`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, you wont be able to access variables in local scope elsewhere in your code.

The code you originally posted was:

```
function process(str) {
    alert(window[str]); // This will alert 'once there lived a king named midas'
} 

function validate() {
    var cont = 'once there lived a king named midas';
    process('cont'); 
}

validate();
```

Another option (rather than putting everything in the 'window' variables map), is to create your own map.

So your code would become:

```
var variables = { }

function process(str) {
    alert(variables[str]); // This will alert 'once there lived a king named midas'
}

function validate() {
    variables['cont'] = 'once there lived a king named midas';
    process('cont');
}

validate();
```

All this is doing is creating a global map which you can add to and index using strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand why you need to pass the variable as a string and why you want to access `cont` via the `window` object. This does what it looks like you expected your code to do:

```
process = function (str) {
    alert(str); // This will alert 'once there lived a king named midas'
}

validate = function () {
    var cont = 'once there lived a king named midas';
    process(cont);
}

validate();
```

FYI: It is generally considered bad practice to declare global variables, especially in a case like this where you don't appear to need them. (I could'd we wrong, though; I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish)

**Edit:** I would suggest using some functions and passing some variables around rather than mucking around with `eval()`-esque variable references. For example, you could implement `makeParam` like so:

```
var cont = 'Boggis, Bunce, and Bean.',
    makeParam = function(str) {
        var param = '',
            i = 0,
            arg = str.split(','),
            l = arg.length;
        while (i < l) {
            if (arg[i + 1].match(/\([a-zA-Z]+\)/)) { // No reason to capture
                param += [arg[1], cont].join('=');
                i += 2;
            } else if (arg[i].match(/\/[a-zA-Z]+\//)) { // No reason to capture
                param += [
                    arg[i], 
                    document.getElementById(arg[i]).value
                ].join('=');
                i += 1;
            } else {
                param += [arg[i], arg[i + 1]].join('=');
                i += 2;
            }
            param += (i + 1 === l) ? '' : '&';
        }
        return param;
    };
param = makeParam('command,insert,/title/,/keywords/,/description/,mode,[1],fckcontent, (cont)');
param === 'command=insert&\
         keywords=somekeywords&\
         description=somedescription&\
         mode=1&\
         fckcontent=Boggis, Bunce, and Bean.';
```

But you'd probably want to pass `cont` into your `makeParam` function.

Comment: i am trying to do like $GLOBALS in php. i hope it would work for local variables like in php. isn't it? oh. does $GLOBALS include local scope? and i have clearly stated the reason for such a need.

Comment: I have added a little of the code which i use to form a query string under the bolded text Edited.

Comment: For one your question was pretty ambiguous when I read it, two JavaScript **is not** PHP so don't treat it that way: use JS idioms and best practices, three your third comment is/was unnecessary and very irritating.

Comment: Also, I feel like you're asking two questions.

Comment: Thank you. comment deleted. i have my function like yours. the only option i was wondering was accessing local variables as window['name'] and since variables in local scope are not referred by window object i am going to use it like a global variable with the help of window object. anyway think you i will cross check my function with yours and will take the options which are needed. my function is here http://vikku.info/codetrash/General.js#MakeParamEx